# SFTP on Unix defaults to Key Authentication

Tags: mac-osx, unix, ssh, sftp

This is probably a simple one for all you Unix whiz' out there, but I can't figure it out, so I am trying to sftp into a windows server from the command line, and the remote refuses connection. When I run it in verbose mode, I can see that the system is trying to use one of my public keys (set up in my ssh config and used for another server that I ssh into) for authentication, when all I want is for it to ask me for a password, here is a sanitized version of the trace:

```
sftp -v<username>@<remote_ip_address>
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/Admin/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <remote_ip_address> [<remote_ip_address>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '<remote_ip_address>' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Admin/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

                            ****USAGE WARNING****

<SFTP Banner  Text>


debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_rsa
Connection closed by <remote_ip_address>
```

When I try this on a windows machine with WinScp or Putty, things work just fine. But I need to get this working on my production server (Centos) where I can't install these or another utilities. 
PS: Im able to reproduce this problem on my mac as well, with the same result, but can't resolve it on either. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sftp -o PubkeyAuthentication=no <user>@<server>
```

That should disable the will of using your public key for this session.